# kri ksiv הַגָּגָה samuel 1 9:26

Tags: tanach, grammar-dikduk, samuel-shmuel-book-of

What is the reason for the kri ksiv in שמואל א' פרק ט' פסוק כ''ו, in which the ksiv is הגג but the kri הַגָּגָה?

I would like to know the reason for how the kri fits in to the pasuk and how the ksiv fits in to the pasuk.

Comment: Unclear of your focus. Do you want to know what the Kri corrects (often k'tiv results from "incorrect" transmissions, and the kri corrects the meaning) or do you wish to know what the k'tiv is trying to convey by being "ungrammatical", here?

Comment: @DanF I would like to know the reason for how the kri fits in to the pasuk and how the ksiv fits in to the pasuk.

Comment: @DanF There, I have edited my question and mzade it more clear.

Comment: In that case, my answer addresses the kri part. As for the ktiv, I have to research it, if there is an answer at all. As stated in my answer, ktiv's often result from errors, which is why the kri is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Biblical Hebrew, when using a preposition such as "to" or "on" followed by the name of a place, Modern Hebrew would have used the word בגג . In Biblical Hebrew, the letter ה is added to the end of the place, instead. So, the meaning , here, is "He called to Samuel **on** the roof".

Compare this, for example, with [Breishit 28:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.2?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all), and see Rashi's grammar explanation, there.

I'm not sure what the reason for the k'tiv is, but the kri offers the correct meaning, here.