# וְיִשְׁתַּחֲווּ vs וישתחו

Tags: grammar-dikduk, torah-reading, parashat-toldot

What is the explanation and reason for the kri-ksiv וְיִשְׁתַּחֲווּ vs וישתחו in בראשית פרק כ''ז פסוק כ''ט?
Please explain how both the kri and the ksiv fit in the pasuk.

Comment: Is that really a Kri/Ktiv? Looks just like a Ktiv Chaser וְיִשְׁתַּחֲוֻ

Comment: mechon mamre says it is

Comment: So...? Must how they choose to categorize anomalous spellings have deeper meanings?

Comment: @DoubleAA, whatever we call it, it's spelled unusually so as to look like "he bowed".

Comment: @msh210 Your wording is ambiguous. Do you mean it was intentionally made to look like a different word or it is spelled unusually such that it happens to look like the way something else is often spelled?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I meant just that it's spelled unusually and, because of that spelling, looks like "he bowed". (The asker here is assuming that that was purposeful on the Author's part, and that seems a reasonable assumption to me also.)

Comment: @msh210 Sounds like you'd do a much better job of writing a compelling question than the OP (has done, at least).

Comment: @DoubleAA, nah, I think it's clear enough and compelling enough. The only differences between his version and mine are: (a) he called it "kri-ksiv" (which is fine even if not technically correct (and I don't know that it's not)); (b) I wrote that the Author presumably did it purposefully (which probably goes without saying, so no biggie to leave it out); and (c) that I translated one of the words. That last point, yes, would improve this post IMO: it should translate both words. (In other news, a link to the verse in question would be nice, so people could see context.)

Comment: Don't the two words have identical meanings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Chizkuni](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.27.29?lang=bi&with=Chizkuni,%20Genesis&lang2=en) explains

(*Source provided from [Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org)*)

> וישתחו לך לאמים, וישתחו כתיב וישתחוו קרי. הוה גביר לאחיך הסכימה דעתו לדעת שגזר הקב"ה ורב יעבד צעיר
>
> ***And nations bow to you:** It is written  וישתחו (in the singular) but read וישתחוו (in the plural). i.e. "**Be a master over your brother"- with agreeing to know that G-d decreed it, and the greater (Esav) will serve the younger
> (Yaakov)***

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!!! this is what I was looking for instead of the unhelpful comments above

Comment: Haha! Welcome to Mi Yodeya, try to ignore the comments unless you think responding to them will be constructive.

Comment: RoshHaYeshiveh That's good advice. Too bad he didn't take it above and declined to improve his question. @Joshua you should learn to take constructive criticism better. Im happy you got lucky and found what you wanted, but you should still improve your question for future readers as well as because you don't know what else will turn up. I for one dont understand how this answers the question, which further indicates a poorly posed question. How can I contribute useful answers if I apparently don't understand what you seek? Take some time to improve your posts and you'll get much better answers

Comment: Incidentally, if a comment is not constructive, just flag for deletion.

Comment: @DoubleAA are you the judge of what a well asked question is over a poorly asked question? Because it seemed pretty clear what was being asked.

Comment: @RoshHaYeshiveh Everyone judges for themselves, I'd think. I don't understand how this post answers it, so something must be off. In general, if one person thinks the question is unclear in some way, there are 1000 other people on the internet who will have the same problem. Mi Yodeya gets thousands of views and it behooves us to keep our content in good shape. If you understand, Kol HaKavod, then maybe you can improve it to help the many others.

Comment: Would you not agree that including things like translations of the words, links to the verses, explanations of what is unexpected in the verse, etc. would improve the question? Does he understand the difference between the singular and the plural and is asking about how they each apply? Does he not know the difference in meaning? There are lots of ways he could write the post such that more people can understand the problem and be interested to either learn or provide a solution.

Comment: FWIW the community voted to close a similar question http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60055/759